# Saving record fails due to uniqueness conflict with itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a procedure which receives two models, one which already exists, and another one which holds new attributes which I want to merge in the first one.

Since other parts of the program are holding the same reference to the new model, I can't just operate on the existing one. Therefor I do the following:

```
def merge(new_model, existing_model)
    new_model.attributes = existing_model.attributes.merge(new_model.attributes)
    new_model.id = existing_model.id
end
```

Now the new_model is being saved which gives me the uniqueness erorr (even though it's technically the same model). I also tried using the reload method, but that yields the same result.

**Background:**

The method above is run in a before_add callback on an association. I want to be able to call update on a model (with nested associations) without having to specify IDs of the nested models. This update is supposed to merge some associations, which is why I try to do the whole merge thing above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the `id` of a model and then save the record expecting the id to be set since the `id` is the primary key of the database. So you are actually creating a whole new record and, thus, the uniqueness validation error. So you'll need to think of some other design to accomplish what you are wanting. It may help to know that what you are trying to do sounds similar to a `deep_dup`, except that ActiveRecord doesn't define this method (but *Hash* does).